# Flutter Web: webview_flutter plugin failed to open url scheme

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I used Flutter to develop a web page, and I want to open another APP using the url scheme when click the floatActionButton.I have some problems now:

**Using the phone app as an example, other apps have the same problem**

1. Use the system browser to load the web page, click the button, you can successfully open the phone APP, as follows:
   [image]
2. I use the [webview_flutter](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/webview_flutter/example) plugin to load the web page in my own program, but it fails to open, as follows:
   [image]

The button click event code in the web page is as follows:
use [url_launcher](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/url_launcher) plugin

```
  void _openAPP() {
    launchUrl(
      Uri(scheme: "tel", host: "12345678"),
      mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
    );
  }
```

I would like to know why the web page loaded using the webview_flutter plugin does not open the url scheme. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the reason, this time I didn't use the url_launcher plugin and used the href jump directly. Need to modify the code in the webview_flutter_android plugin.

1. button click event code

```dart
    import 'dart:html' as html;
    void _openAPP() {
        html.window.location.href = "tel://123456789";
    }
```

2. modify the code in the webview_flutter_android plugin.

> io/flutter/plugins/webviewflutter/WebViewClientHostApiImpl.java

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
      // -- new code start
      final String url = request.getUrl().toString();
      if (!url.startsWith("http") || !url.startsWith("https")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
      }
      // -- new code end
      if (flutterApi != null) {
        flutterApi.requestLoading(this, view, request, reply -> {});
      }
      return shouldOverrideUrlLoading;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have to treat your Android platform project to allow the action. E.g. you can try changing AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: thanks! I am using the phone app as an example, other apps have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The proper format is `tel:12345678` not `tel://12345678`.

```
Uri.parse("tel:12345678")
```

Comment: thanks! After writing this, you still need to add an interception method in the webView android plugin